# After a while, glGenBuffers is very slow

Tags: opengl, libgdx, lwjgl

I'm programming an in-game editor for my simple 2D game, where meshes are dynamically created and removed quite often. I'm using *libgdx*

Everything works fine, except that the editor becomes slow. It responds on input events quite late.

To find the weak point in my code (which isn't optimized at all atm), I run *jprofiler* and profiled the CPU. It turns out, that *glGenBuffers* tooks over 2 sec for 14 invocations! That is for 7 meshes, with one vertex and index buffer each. Actually, I have a quite fast machine (i7-4790T, GTX980m, 16GB...), so this shouldn't be the problem here.

I just want to know how this is possible since I have no idea.

[image: jprofiler]

Comment: Are you deleting the buffers you aren't using anymore? Just based on the symptoms, it could be a memory leak. Can you look at overall memory usage by your app, and see if it's increasing?

Comment: Just wanted to remark that the buffers will likely be held in your graphics card memory, so you might not be able to see your RAM usage go up. Otherwise agreed, you should always clean up your buffers by calling `glDeleteBuffers`.

Answer (score 0):

1st two comments were right. I was rebuilding a large part of the scene to check, if it still exists (not that clever in general). If it still exists, the rebuilded part wan't disposed. Only replaced parts were replaced correctly. :/ .

I found that issue using jprofiler and profiling memory, as suggested in comment 1.

I didn't check the graphics memory, but there is no other way, that the garbage is there, too.

Answer (score 0):

Buffers are always stored in memory. Cleanup is always needed, frame-buffers, byte-buffers etc.